# CakePHP Routers with language, slug, pagination

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, routes, pagination, cakephp-1.3

Using CakePHP 1.3 I am trying to get routers with language, slug, pagination, order .

Currently I have these:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect("/:controller/:slug", array('action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('slug')));
Router::connect("/:lang", array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'), array('lang' => 'fr|en|de'));
Router::connect("/:lang/:controller/:slug", array('action' => 'view'), array('lang' => 'fr|en|de', 'pass' => array('slug')));
```

and those are working with language and slug set or slug and pagination , but all three of them fails:

```
OK - /pages/view/page-slug/page:2
OK - /fr/pages/page-slug
FAIL - /pages/view/page-slug/page:2/lang:fr
```

I have tried

```
<?php $this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs)); ?>
```

before the paginator but still the same result

Answer (score 1):

Just try this code

```
Router::connectNamed(array('language','pagination','order','slug'));
    Router::connect('/lang/pagination/:slug:order', array(
        'plugin' => false,
        'controller' => 'pages', 
        'action' => 'index',
        ),array(
            "pass"=>array("lang","pagination","slug","order")
        ),array(
            'pagination' => '[0-9]+',
            'order' => '[0-9]+',
        )
    );
```